# selecting based on null

Tags: c#, linq

I'm building a dynamic query and doing a join between 2 entities: the query being built and a table.

I have:

```
var TheQuery = ...;

TheQuery = from x in TheQuery
           join c in MyDataContext.TheTable on
           x.ID equals c.ID
           where "there's no matching element in TheTable"
           select x
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking here... what exactly are you trying to do, and what's actually happening?

Comment: Are you wanting to do the equivalent of an outer join here??

Comment: I want to keep in TheQuery only the elements that are not in TheTable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do a Left outer join with LINQ you have to use `join .. into` and [`DefaultIfEmpty()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360179.aspx):

```
TheQuery = from x in TheQuery
           join c in MyDataContext.TheTable on x.ID equals c.ID into outer
           from o in outer.DefaultIfEmpty()
           where o == null
           select x
```